# Android app won't update; must uninstall first

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I created an Android app using Xamarin.Android.  It runs great on all the devices I've tested it on.  However, when I try to distribute an update to my users (ad hoc, not through Google Play Store), on a lot of devices I get a message that says "App not installed."  The only way to get the update to install is to first uninstall it, and then the updated version works just fine.

Aside from code changes, for each update I'm incrementing the Version Name and Version Code.  I'm also signing it each time with the same Signing Key.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Thanks.

Comment: Same happened to me too. I tried changing package name and then it installed successfully. But I don't know whether it helps in your case. I'm sure it will get installed if you change the package name.

Comment: @mohammedmazin but change package name means different app? Just want to update.